# Is there an easier way to persist an object to db when using angular-meteor?

Tags: angular-meteor

I really like meteor-angular, however, in the following code snippet, I think there is still friction when persisting changes back to the db. For example, in this code sample:

```
saveParty(name: string, description: string) {
        Parties.update(this.selectedParty._id, {$set: {name: name, description: description}});
    }
```

it is going to difficult to manually type "name: name, description: description" if there were a large number of fields.

Is it possible to do something like (kind of like what breezsjs does):

```
saveParty() {
        Parties.save(this.selectedParty);
    }
```

or better yet:

```
 saveParty() {
            this.selectedParty.Save();
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes :)
Take a look at AngularMeteorCollection methods here - http://angular-meteor.com/api/AngularMeteorCollection#methods

AngularMeteorObject methods here - http://angular-meteor.com/api/AngularMeteorObject
and

And the examples at the bottom